# How to add text above it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm making a layout:

[image: layout]

Here is a code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#373c5c"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >




    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/list_offer_item_container"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgcreditcompany"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_height="36dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:textColor="#48899f"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsizeearncredit_title"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtdesc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="#80869c"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsizeearncredit_desc"
                android:text="This is a description of the offer and this is just a demo to show off 3 lines stacking correctly on top of each other"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:gravity="end"

            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

            <TextView android:id="@+id/list_offer_badge_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/list_offer_item_container"
                android:textColor="@color/md_amber_700"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:text=""/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/nextArrow"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:tint="@color/md_grey_300"
            android:rotation="180"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:padding="@dimen/two" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

How to add an text above the 'button style' linear layout?

I want for example "Hello dear user! Check it below".

Where put textview, where add more layout or whatever?

Comment: Can you be more specific?
What 'button style' linear layout? Which one of those is the one you want add text above?

Comment: @KamilGryboś above this one: @+id/list_offer_item_container

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple! 
You have to add TextView, with id (`text`, for example) and, in your LinearLayout you need to add line `android:layout_below="@+id/text"`. Optional, you can specify attribute `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` in TextView.

Just use code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#373c5c"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />


    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/list_offer_item_container"
                  android:layout_below="@+id/text"
                  android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                  android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="@drawable/shape"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgcreditcompany"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_height="36dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:textColor="#48899f"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsizeearncredit_title"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtdesc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="#80869c"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsizeearncredit_desc"
                android:text="This is a description of the offer and this is just a demo to show off 3 lines stacking correctly on top of each other"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:gravity="end"

            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

            <TextView android:id="@+id/list_offer_badge_text"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_above="@+id/list_offer_item_container"
                      android:textColor="@color/md_amber_700"
                      android:textSize="12sp"
                      android:visibility="gone"
                      android:text=""/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/nextArrow"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:tint="@color/md_grey_300"
            android:rotation="180"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:padding="@dimen/two" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Above

```
 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/list_offer_item_container"
```

put your `TextView` or whatever you want. So something like

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/myTV"
    // other attributes />
```

Then in 
    `<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/list_offer_item_container"`

add `android:layout_below="@id/myTV"`

By default, `RelativeLayout` puts it's elements at the top-left until you specify otherwise. So adding this will put your `LinearLayout` below the `TextView`.

I think the confusion is on how `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout` work. You have `orientation` in your `RelativeLayout` which does nothing. `RelativeLayout` puts it's elements in the order you tell it by the attributes such as `layout_below` and `layout_above`. `LinearLayout`, however, adds them in the order in which they show in the xml file which is why `orientation` matters in `LinearLayout` but not `RelativeLayout`.

You'll want to look at [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) and other parts of the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) to better understand how the layouts work and which is best in your specific cases.